# How to set only for x64 mode in Android

Tags: java, android, linux

I want to build my android app only for 64bit mode.
I already changed the settings like this
By the way, when I checked the log and it says it is 32 bit.
Can I know the cause?
Please tell me how to build in 64 bit mode.

```
    defaultConfig {
        
        minSdk 30
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "x86_64", "arm64-v8a"
        }
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

I checked the log with this code.

```
String realArch = arch != null && arch.endsWith("64")
                || wow64Arch != null && wow64Arch.endsWith("64")
                ? "64" : "32";
        if(realArch == "64"){
            System.out.println("Start---64bit");
            exeMain();
        }else{
            System.out.println("Start---32bit");//always showed this log
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't shown us `arch` or `wow64Arch`, what if both are `null`?

Comment: Java object code doesn't have any architecture. Do you have any native (C/C++/Rust) code?